# Error:"invalid comparator" when sorting using custom comparison function

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to sort some integers and make odd integers followed by even ones. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Here's my code:

```
int w[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
sort(w,w+6,[](const int&i,const int&j)->bool {
return (i&1)==(j&1)//When both are odd or even, the order is OK
||i&1;//if one is odd and one is even,check if the first one is odd
});
```

When executed, it encounters an error says "Expression: invalid comparator". I don't know why it would cause this error. How to modify it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`sort` requires a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Your comparator isn't one. Among many other things, for a strict weak ordering, `comp(x, x)` must be `false`.

`sort` is the wrong algorithm for this anyway (yes, you can contort it to do what you want; no, you shouldn't do it). What you want to do is a *partition*. For that, we have [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition):

```
std::partition(std::begin(w), std::end(w), [](int x) { return x % 2 != 0; });
```

Or [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), if you want the partition to be stable (preserve the relative order of elements).

Comment: … it *is* possible to abuse `sort` for partitioning, but this is the best answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter it would be `(x % 2) < (y % 2)`? (or `>` didn't think hard about which)